# VBA to pick elements in one column that sum to a setpoint, and corresponding elements in next column to average to a setpoint?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

**Note:** the solutions below are from excel functions, and are just to illustrate what the problem is. The final solution needs to be VBA (or an excel function that will work in the space provided i.e no additional space).

As per the image,  my file will have two columns (of any amount of rows).

I need to scan both columns to find any number of column 1 values that when summed match the setpoint (E2) and column 2 values that when averaged,  match the setpoint (E3). One constraint is that the chosen values in column 1 and column 2 must be from the same row (shown in the image highlighted in blue and green).

**Explanation of the solution below:** 
What it should do is say 'A2 and A6 sum to 7 (match cell E2), and the corresponding B2 and B6 average to 3' (match cell E3). Therefore, these rows should be selected/highlighted in any appropriate way.

**Example that does not work as a solution:**
It can't be A4 and A5 because although they add to 7, B4 and B5 average to 1.5, not the setpoint of 3.

Image of the problem (with a solution highlighted):

[image]

**Update:** A solution for one of the cases was found on /r/excel. This solution (below) works only for the case where there are two rows that will sum/average to the setpoints. It will not work for cases where more than two rows are required. The solution should work for any number of rows required.

**Solution to 'two row' case:**
[image]

**Example where three rows would be required (Solution is the first three rows):**
[image]

**Reason for this solution:** B6:B8 sums to the setpoint of 8 and C6:C8 average to the setpoint of 3

**Note:** VBA Code would be preferable due to the need to add two extra columns at least with the excel function method.

Comment: Hi, I removed the attempted solution as it would only cause confusion. SA and S have been removed. In regards to the solution, it can_look_like anything, as long as the 'chosen rows' are clear. I chose to highlight the cells in this case manually, but it could take the form of a third column with a 1 signifying 'chosen' and a '0' signifying not chosen etc. Is this clear?

Comment: Also, I have posted a similar question before to this one. It has generally been a long-winded description. If there is a more concise way to explain this I will approve the edit.

Comment: Sure, but it may just be a point of confusion as it does not work as intended. `` =IF(OR(C1="SA",C1=-2),-2,IF(OR(C1="S",C1=-1),IF(AVERAGE($A2:$B2)=$E$3,"SA",-1),IF(SUM($A2:$B2)=$E$2,"S",""))) ``. Formula goes in box C2

Comment: The function above - using the image attached as an example - will in this case find the same solution as I have highlighted above, but for the wrong reason. The sum setpoint is 7 and row 7 adds to 7, the average setpoint is 3 and row 2 averages to 3. What it should do is say 'A2 and A6 sum to 7, and the corresponding B2 and B6 average to 3'. Does this make sense?

Comment: Exactly correct. Ok, I thought including an error term would be easier but if it isnt thats ok too.

Comment: Ok I can do this, but I wanted to avoid losing people with excessive writing. Added your comment as an example that would not work.

Comment: Is row 5 and 7 a Match? If you have only 2 rows as per your example, it's not to hard but not sure if this is an option. Regardless, I think this will require VBa, not a formula

Comment: Yes row 5 and 7 is a match. I only need to find one solution though, any solution is ok. I thought it might require some kind of 'for' loop or maybe a 'while' loop to incorporate an error term, but I'm not sure. Is this the right forum to find VBA code for this?

Comment: I had not downvoted, but I have upvoted now. @NoviceCoder11 you've done a good job incorporating feedback to REALLY improve this question - it was unanswerable as you initially posted it, this morning. As to your solution, there's no doubt it can't be done without VBA.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have been posting and reposting for a few weeks now. Hopefully with this new wording it is understandable! Thanks to @Dave also for the edit.

Comment: Yes it is right website. The is not a forum though. Its a Q and A site :)

Comment: @NoviceCoder11,, logically your question is wrong,, my experience says that Excel can find cells in Column to get the equivalent of the `SUM` value in `E2` & Average in `E4`,, but you cant restrict to certain cells only !!

Comment: @rajesh how is the question wrong? It makes perfect sense?

Comment: Solution found to the case where only two rows are required to fit the setpoints. However, it should also work in the case where a number of rows are needed to sum/average to the setpoints. Note: It does not have to be an excel function, it can be VBA code instead.

Comment: @NoviceCoder11,, to match the `SUM` in `E2` Excel may find all possible combinations but it's logically incorrect that this should be restricted to certain cells. Considering your example it should be `A2` & `A3` as first occurrence instead of `A2` & `A6` !!

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. Yes you are correct, A2 and A3 is the first occurrence (assuming an iteration method). I can change the example to show this.